# Why is unused memory counted as used at the same time?

Tags: windows, memory, windows-11, memory-management, memory-leaks

So I'm regularly using a VM with Hyper-V on my Windows 11 host system (Windows 11 Pro, 64 bit, 16GB RAM, Core i5) without any issues. But since yesterday I noticed that I don't have enough available RAM for powering up my VM. In task manager I can see that I'm constantly running at very high memory usage (70-90%) But the memory usages of the individual processes don't add up to the 12-14GB that I'm supposedly using.

So I downloaded RamMap and tried to figure out what's going on. I've read many posts, where people with similar issues report to see high numbers in Paged Table, Mapped File or Driver Locked. But for me I can see that 7GB are marked as unused (grey area in the screenshot)!!! If it's unused, then why is it not free for usage and appears in the sum of used memory adding up to 13GB??? How do I free up this memory??? Restarting my PC does not appear to achieve anything.

Any hints/help greatly appreciated!

See the posted screenshot of both task manager and RamMap taken at the same instant:

[image]

Comment: What do you see in RamMap after running [EmptyStandbyList.exe](https://wj32.org/wp/software/empty-standby-list/?fbclid=IwAR2UMTIKTmCGve1wWCV72UOrqF5PZEH6baQdufoSWGlO2WZfuF7LSjt7q20)? Please also add a screenshot of the Performance tab in Task Manager.

Comment: I've updated the screenshot so that it includes the performance tab (the word "Arbeitsspeicher" meaning RAM). I've not run this EmptyStandbyList.exe as I don't really trust this tool to fiddle around with my memory management. But luckily the RamMap (from SysInternals) has also functions for emptying out standby list, modified pages, etc. Tried all of them, doesn't really do anything. In fact I'm pretty sure that's not my problem anyway, because the standby only has a grand total of 2.5 GB, the lion share of wasted memory seems to be this "unused" section, that's somehow still not free to use

Answer (score 1):

I think RamMap is just misreporting the information, or that it's us
that do not know how to read it. Note that RamMap executes in user-space,
so is limited to data that is available via Windows API. It doesn't
have direct access to kernel data.

The Performance tab in Task Manager shows clearly that Windows is using
13,8 GB, and that there are 2,0 GB still available. Together this makes
15,8 GB, which just about accounts for your entire RAM.

There are no unused 7 GB to be found anywhere in Task Manager,
so clearly "Unused" in RamMap means something else. These 7 GB are
probably included in Task Manager in the section of "In Use"
(your "In Verwendung").

From other posts I have seen on the internet, I got the impression that
the "Unused" section of RamMap actually stands for memory that it cannot
analyze, usually driver data. RamMap cannot analyze driver data,
as this requires direct kernel access.

Finding out what causes this allocation is a big problem.
You could try as a start to boot in Safe Mode and see if this still
happens.
In this mode, only Microsoft drivers are allowed to execute.
This might give us some more information about the problem.

Comment: OK, thanks for that clarification. Will try it in safe mode next

Comment: I don't know what exactly happened. I clicked the repai option in the boot menu while rebooting, it said it couldn't repair anything and lo and behold the problem is gone (down to less than 5GB while idling)?!? Thanks anyway for your suggestion!

Comment: The reboot liberated the memory used by this driver. It can come back after using this driver for some time.